# Enhanced Auth Dialog "This app will share.." Content Incorrect. Modifiable?

Tags: object, action, customization, facebook-opengraph, authentication

The Facebook Enhanced Auth Dialog has a block of text at lower-right that describes what the app will share with others that seems to be defaulted to a generic set of actions & objects.

[image]

Specifically, the dialog for my app's auth dialog currently reads:

> This app will share [objects] you [action]ed, [objects] you became friends with and other activity on Facebook.

How does one alter it to read a particular set of object/action pairings? For example: "This app will share routes you ran..." or "This app will share movies you rated..."?

Is there a way to specify particular pairs for usage in this dialog?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook selected the action object pairs to show based on the actions/objects which have been approved and are available to be used.

No, app owners currently don't have control over which action/object pairs are shown.

Comment: Ok. Well, I haven't submitted any for approval yet, but one of my action object pairs does show up in the dialog, but the other is showing "musicians you became friends with" and my app has nothing to do with music. I'm just concerned about having the dialog still show that to potential new users.

Comment: I assume the action object pair it is showing already is pre-approved because it's a built-in object type.

Comment: I have a feeling it's something to do with https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/ - where music is being associated with the og:profile property.

Answer (score 0):

Use the developer tool to create verbs and nouns.

Comment: Yes, I've done this, although I haven't submitted the custom objects for approvals yet.